# What can I change if the turtle-code logs me out of python 3 Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, logout, turtle-graphics, macos-mojave

If I run this Code on Python3 (Anaconda Jupyter 6.0.0) I'm getting logged out automatically. I use a Mac with macOS Mojave.
The code is from the book "How to think like a Computer Scientist". So I'm at the beginning to learn some python.

I already tried to delete the turtle.py files in the library, but it didn't work either.

```
import turtle
window = turtle.Screen() 
alex = turtle.Turtle()
alex.forward(50)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)
window.mainloop()
```

When I run the code I get logged out. When I log in again, Jupyter just shows a window with "error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a by-pass than an answer as I am still trying to figure it out myself. I have a macbook and am experiencing the same behavior with PyCharm and Anaconda.

If you want to learn python, the code above runs fine if you instead install the base python interpreter from https://www.python.org/. It includes the turtle module and you can change it in your IDE so that this new interpreter is the default rather than Anaconda. If I figure it out what is happening with Anaconda before someone else, I will let you know.